# Automatically attaching to process on SEGV and other fatal signals (panic_action)

Tags: c, unix, gdb, signals, lldb

**Background**

Code to support a 'panic_action' was recently added to the FreeRADIUS v3.0.x, v2.0.x and master branches.

When `radiusd` (main FreeRADIUS process) receives a fatal signal (SIGFPE, SIGABRT, SIGSEGV etc...), the signal handler executes a predefined 'panic_action' which is a snippet of shell code passed to `system()`. The signal handler performs basic substitution for `%e` and `%p` writing in the values of the current binary name, and the current PID.

This should in theory allow a debugger like gdb or lldb to attach to the process (`panic_action = lldb -f %e -p %p`), either to perform interactive debugging, or to automate collection of a backtrace. This actually works well on my system OSX 10.9.2 with `lldb`, but only for `SIGABRT`.

**Problem**

This doesn't seem to work for other signals like `SIGSEGV`. The mini backtrace from `execinfo` is valid, but when `lldb` or `gdb` attach to the process, they only get the backtrace from for the signal handler.

There doesn't seem to be a way in `lldb` to switch to an arbitrary frame address.

Does anyone know if there's any way of forcing the signal handler to execute in the same stack as the the thread that received the signal? Or why when lldb attaches the backtraces don't show the full stack.

The actual output looks like:

```
FATAL SIGNAL: Segmentation fault: 11
Backtrace of last 12 frames:
0   libfreeradius-radius.dylib          0x000000010cf1f00f fr_fault + 127
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8b03e5aa _sigtramp + 26
2   radiusd                             0x000000010ce7617f do_compile_modsingle + 3103
3   libfreeradius-server.dylib          0x000000010cef3780 fr_condition_walk + 48
4   radiusd                             0x000000010ce7710f modcall_pass2 + 191
5   radiusd                             0x000000010ce7713f modcall_pass2 + 239
6   radiusd                             0x000000010ce7078d virtual_servers_load + 685
7   radiusd                             0x000000010ce71df1 setup_modules + 1633
8   radiusd                             0x000000010ce6daae read_mainconfig + 2526
9   radiusd                             0x000000010ce78fe6 main + 1798
10  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8580a5fd start + 1
11  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
Calling: lldb -f /usr/local/freeradius/sbin/radiusd -p 1397
Current executable set to '/usr/local/freeradius/sbin/radiusd' (x86_64).
Attaching to process with:
    process attach -p 1397
Process 1397 stopped
(lldb) bt
error: libfreeradius-radius.dylib debug map object file '/Users/arr2036/Documents/Repositories/freeradius-server-fork/build/objs//Users/arr2036/Documents/Repositories/freeradius-server-master/src/lib/debug.o' has changed (actual time is 0x530f3d21, debug map time is 0x530f37a5) since this executable was linked, file will be ignored
* thread #1: tid = 0x8d824, 0x00007fff867fee38 libsystem_kernel.dylib`wait4 + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff867fee38 libsystem_kernel.dylib`wait4 + 8
    frame #1: 0x00007fff82869090 libsystem_c.dylib`system + 425
    frame #2: 0x000000010cf1f2e1 libfreeradius-radius.dylib`fr_fault + 849
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8b03e5aa libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 26
(lldb)
```

**Code**

The relevant code for `fr_fault()` is here:https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/b7ec8c37c7204accbce4be4de5013397ab662ea3/src/lib/debug.c#L227

and `fr_set_signal()` the function used to setup signal handlers is here: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/0cf0e88704228e8eac2948086e2ba2f4d17a5171/src/lib/misc.c#L61

*As the links contain commit hashes the code should be static*

**EDIT**
Finally with version lldb-330.0.48 on OSX 10.10.4 lldb can now go past _sigtram.

```
frame #2: 0x000000010b96c5f7 libfreeradius-radius.dylib`fr_fault(sig=11) + 983 at debug.c:735
   732              FR_FAULT_LOG("Temporarily setting PR_DUMPABLE to 1");
   733          }
   734  
-> 735          code = system(cmd);
   736  
   737          /*
   738           *  We only want to error out here, if dumpable was originally disabled
(lldb) 
frame #3: 0x00007fff8df77f1a libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 26
libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp:
    0x7fff8df77f1a <+26>: decl   -0x16f33a50(%rip)
    0x7fff8df77f20 <+32>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff8df77f23 <+35>: movl   $0x1e, %esi
    0x7fff8df77f28 <+40>: callq  0x7fff8df794d8            ; symbol stub for: __sigreturn
(lldb) 
frame #4: 0x000000010bccb027 rlm_json.dylib`_json_map_proc_get_value(ctx=0x00007ffefa62dbe0, out=0x00007fff543534b8, request=0x00007ffefa62da30, map=0x00007ffefa62aaf0, uctx=0x00007fff54353688) + 391 at rlm_json.c:191
   188          }
   189          vp = map->op;
   190  
-> 191          if (value_data_steal(vp, &vp->data, vp->da->type, value) < 0) {
   192              REDEBUG("Copying data to attribute failed: %s", fr_strerror());
   193              talloc_free(vp);
   194              goto error;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in lldb related to backtracing through `_sigtramp`, the asynchronous signal handler in user processes.  Unfortunately I can't suggest a workaround for this problem.  It has been fixed in the top of tree sources for lldb at http://lldb.llvm.org/ if you're willing to build from source (see the "Source" and "Build" sidebars).  But Xcode 5.0 and the next dot release are going to have real problems backtracing past `_sigtramp`.